Error from an Angular unit test (with Jest) saying "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading flexibleConnectedTo)"
I'm testing a standalone cmp, which imports the following modules
imports: [CommonModule, MatIconModule, MatExpansionModule, MatDialogModule, MatMenuModule],

In the HTML
<div class="category__extensions__lists__item__menu" [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">...</div>
   <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
     <button 
       [disableRipple]="true" 
       mat-menu-item 
       class="delete-btn installed__uninstall"
       (click)="uninstall(category.extensions[installed.id], installed.version)">
         Uninstall
      </button>
   </mat-menu>

In my test
@Component({
  selector: 'exa-wrapper-testing',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ExtensionGroupItemComponent],
  template: '<exa-extension-group-item [category]="category"></exa-extension-group-item>',
  styles: [':host { display: flex; width: 1000px; height: 800px; }'],
})
class WrapperTestingComponent {
  category?: Category;
}

describe('ExtensionGroupItemComponent', () => {
  let wrapperCmp: WrapperTestingComponent;
  let cmp: ExtensionGroupItemComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<WrapperTestingComponent>;
  let debugElement: DebugElement;
  
  const getVersion = (version: string, latest = false, installed = false, deprecated = false): ExtensionVersion => ({
    version,
    latest,
    deprecated,
    installed,
  });
  
  let dialog: MatDialog;
  let loader: HarnessLoader;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    await TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        WrapperTestingComponent,
        ExtensionGroupItemComponent,
        MatExpansionModule,
        MatIconTestingModule,
        MatDialogModule,
        ModalInstallingExtensionComponent,
        ModalUninstallingExtensionComponent,
        NoopAnimationsModule,
        OverlayModule,
        MatMenuModule
      ],
    })
    .overrideComponent(ExtensionGroupItemComponent, {
      remove: { imports: [ModalInstallingExtensionComponent] },
      add: { imports: [MockComponent(ModalInstallingExtensionComponent)] },
    })
    .compileComponents();

    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(WrapperTestingComponent);
    wrapperCmp = fixture.componentInstance;
    wrapperCmp.category = getExtensionsCategories()[CategoryIds.CLOUD_STORAGE_IMPORTER];
    cmp = fixture.debugElement.children[0].componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;
    dialog = TestBed.inject(MatDialog);
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
  });

it(`when on a installed extension the 3-dots menu icon is clicked,
      it should display the ModalUninstallingExtensionComponent`, async () => {
    wrapperCmp.category = getExtensionsCategories()[CategoryIds.SECURITY];
    wrapperCmp.category!.available = 1;
    wrapperCmp.category!.extensions = {
      'id-0': {
        id: 'id-0',
        name: 'name-0',
        description: '',
        categoryId: wrapperCmp.category!.id,
        installableVersions: [getVersion('1.0.0', true, true)],
      }
    };
    fixture.detectChanges();

    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.category__info__values li:nth-child(1) label')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Available');
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.category__info__values li:nth-child(1) div')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('1');
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.category__info__values li:nth-child(2) label')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('Installed');
    expect(debugElement.query(By.css('.category__info__values li:nth-child(2) div')).nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('1');
    
    jest.spyOn(ModalUninstallingExtensionComponent, 'open');

    debugElement.query(By.css('mat-expansion-panel mat-panel-title')).nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
  
    // test that there is one 3-dots menu
    expect(debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.category__extensions__lists__item__menu'))).toHaveLength(1);
    expect(debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.category__extensions__lists__item__menu'))[0].nativeElement.textContent).toEqual('...');
    
// on the line below I'm getting the following error -> console.error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'flexibleConnectedTo')
    debugElement.queryAll(By.css('.category__extensions__lists__item__menu'))[0].nativeElement.click();
    fixture.detectChanges();
}));

});

so on the line when I click on the item that should trigger the matmenu and make it to appear, I'm getting an error saying console.error ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'flexibleConnectedTo')
Does anyone have an idea of how to fix it?
I'm using

"@angular/core": "16.2.1",
"@angular/material": "16.2.1",
"jest": "29.5.0",
"@nx/jest": "16.9.1",
"jest-preset-angular": "13.1.1",
"nx": "^16.10.0",

